# How can I make Windows screen timeout settings permanent?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, lock-screen

My Windows 10 screen timeout settings are always:

Screen:

On battery power turn off after 5 minutes.

When plugged in, turn off after 10 minutes.

Sleep:

On battery power, PC goes to sleep after Never.

When plugged in, PC goes to sleep after Never.

I keep setting these to 30 minutes/60 minutes/60 minutes/2 hours, but they don't save. They stay for around an hour and then reset. How can I make these settings permanent?

Comment: Screen timeout settings work properly and hold their settings on all my machines here.   Open cmd.exe, run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  and then run SFC /SCANNOW.  Restart and test.  Also, update your BIOS, Chipset and Power Drivers.

Answer (score 0):

There's most likely some power management software which is struggling for this setting. Laptops often have this. A search for "power" in Start should reveal it.

You can either uninstall the software or attempt to set your desired settings from within the program.

Answer (score 0):

The screen timeout settings should persist across reboots. So I think any third party app is causing the problem and it is resetting screen timeout settings.

You can try a clean boot. A clean boot means to boot windows cleanly without loading starup apps or any other things. Open System configuration (msconfig.exe) and go to the Startup tab, then click Hide all microsoft services. Then unccheck the apps which you suspect, and then reboot. Then inspect for the issues.

If any third party app is not the culprit then you can run a SFC Scan using `sfc /scannow` or Run windows disk image troubleshooter with `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` from an elevated command prompt.